# Why I can't get a right answer when I press 's' and 'u'?

Tags: c, debugging

I am writing a simple program to judge the day by the first letter in C. I hava some trouble debugging .Thank all you who see and answer the question in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
//Sunday  Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday 

char letter;
printf("Input the first letter.\n");
scanf("%c",&letter); 

switch(letter)
{
    case 's': printf("Please in put the second number:\n");
          if(getchar()=='u')
              printf("It's Sunday\n");
          else if(getchar()=='a')
              printf("It's Saturday\n");
          else 
              printf("Input wrong!\n");             
          break;
    case 'm': printf("It's Monday\n");
          break;
    case 't': printf("Please in put the second number\n");
          if(getchar()=='u')
              printf("It's Tuesday\n");
          else if(getchar()=='h')
              printf("It's Thursday\n");
          else 
              printf("Input wrong!\n");             
          break;
    case 'w':  printf("It's Wednesday.");
           break;
    case 'f':  printf("It's Friday.  "); 
           break;
    default : printf("You input the wrong letter \n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `gcc -g -Wall -pedantic` is your friend. Use your debugger!

Comment: `else if (getchar()==...)` - the second `getchar` will read the _third_ letter of the word (the second letter is already swallowed by the previous `getchar`).

Comment: Write `printf("_%c_",letter);` after `scanf` to see what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at a chunk of your code:

```
      if(getchar()=='u')
          printf("It's Sunday\n");
      else if(getchar()=='a')
          printf("It's Saturday\n");
      else 
          printf("Input wrong!\n");             
      break;
```

Here's how that code will execute:

1. `getchar()` will be called and we will compare it against `'u'`. Let's assume that fails. This means that we have consumed one character from the input keyboard.
2. `getchar()` will be called **again** and compared to `'a'`!

Instead of this, you probably want something like:

```
      int c = getchar();
      if(c == 'u')
          printf("It's Sunday\n");
      else if(c == 'a')
          printf("It's Saturday\n");
      else 
          printf("Input wrong!\n");             
      break;
```

Now, you're going to still have additional problems because after your `scanf()`, the next character in the input stream is going to be `'\n'`.

To get around this, use `scanf(" %c", &letter)` for both the first and second character of the input.

Comment: Suggest `int c = getchar();`, not that it makes a difference in this code, but better habit for saving `getchar();` values.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `stdin` is buffered and includes `'\n'`.

```
printf("Input the first letter.\n");
scanf("%c", &letter);
```

Say the user is thinking "saturday".  When the user enters <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `scanf("%c",...)` will consume the `'s'`, leaving the `'\n'` in `stdin`.

When code gets to

```
case 's': 
  printf("Please input the second letter:\n");
  if(getchar()=='u')
    printf("It's Sunday\n");
```

`getchar()` will return `'\n'`.

Instead, read the input and toss any preceding white-space with

```
scanf(" %c",&letter); // Note leading space.
```

Also, as others noted, do not read a `char` again when trying to distinguish Saturday and Sunday.

```
// Ensure letter has _some_ known value should scanf() reach EOF.
char letter = 0;
printf("Input the first letter.\n");
scanf(" %c", &letter); 

switch(letter) {
    case 's': 
      printf("Please input the second letter:\n");
      scanf(" %c", &letter); 
      if (letter == 'u')
        printf("It's Sunday\n");
      else if (letter == 'a')
        printf("It's Saturday\n");
      else 
        printf("Input wrong!\n");             
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using getchar() twice for one case statement. That's not how you should do it. You should getchar() first, then save that into a variable then compare it. That's the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

For example to get to saturday you need to type s followed by summat not u then a

Ditto for tues and thurs

Most probably at the terminal they need to hit the enter key before your program gets a look in. So just read a string

Comment: His logic is correct - it's just that he doesn't understand how scanf works.

Comment: @nishantjr - Eh? `getchar` consumes a character. Putting the fact that a return is required to send it to the program. Type in s. Then `getchar` not a `u` as the persojn typed in `a`. But that is consumed. So to get saturday you need to type in `saa`

Comment: Sorry, I should have said: he doesn't understand how getchar works. He understands the how the branching happens - but assumes that the char is not consumed.

Comment: @nishantjr - Therefore his(?) logic is not correct

Comment: Shis assumption that getchar() does not consume a character is incorrect. If that was true, the program would work fine.

Comment: @nishantjr - Therefore your logic is incorrect